# ActiveAdmin Categories always goes to default setting in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, activeadmin

Hi I´m learning to use ActiveAdmin by building an rails App.

I've a products and a category model which are related `Product belongs to category`.

In the Admin Panel I can create Categories and Products

When I´m creating new product and assigning it to a category I have created the product always ends up belonging to a category called "No Category"

this "No category" option is supposed to be default if no other category is assigned to the product.

I´m not sure why this is happening since I can choose from multiple categories that I've created.

this is my product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :page


    validates :title, :description, presence: true
    validates :price_usd, :price_isl, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true


 has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500#", thumb: "100x100#" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/
end
```

and this is my category.rb model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :products

end
```

And here is a copy of my Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160826161114) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "namespace"
    t.text     "body"
    t.string   "resource_id",   null: false
    t.string   "resource_type", null: false
    t.integer  "author_id"
    t.string   "author_type"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id", using: :btree
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace", using: :btree
  add_index "active_admin_comments", ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id", using: :btree

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  end

  add_index "admin_users", ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "admin_users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "pages", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at",              null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",              null: false
    t.integer  "category_id", default: 5
  end

  add_index "pages", ["category_id"], name: "index_pages_on_category_id", using: :btree

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "image"
    t.text     "description"
    t.decimal  "price_usd"
    t.decimal  "price_isl"
    t.datetime "created_at",                     null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                     null: false
    t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer  "category_id",        default: 4
  end

  add_index "products", ["category_id"], name: "index_products_on_category_id", using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "pages", "categories"
  add_foreign_key "products", "categories"
end
```

Comment: How are you creating a new product and adding it to a category?

Comment: Show your `app/admin/product.rb` file. Have you included `:category_id` to the `permit_params` list?